# Javascript propagate JQuery post error inside addEventListener to outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I am trying to propagate the error generated inside `addEventListener` made by a JQuery post request to the outside try and catch block. So far, what I have tried:

1. catch the error from the request with `catch`, then `throw` it to the outside block

```
      try {
        document.getElementById("billing-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
          $.post("/test_request", { token: 123 })
          .catch (error => {
            console.log(error)
            throw (error)
          })
        })  
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Failed miserably

2. using `async` `await` for the request and let it fail

```
      try {
        document.getElementById("billing-button").addEventListener("click", async () => {
          await $.post("/test_request", { token: 123 })
        })  
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Did not work

3. Using another `try catch` inside the `addEventListener` then `throw` the error to the outside block:

```
      try {
        document.getElementById("billing-button").addEventListener("click", async () => {
          try {
            await $.post("/test_request", { token: 123 });
          }
          catch (error) {
            throw error
          }
        })  
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Also does not work.

Help please.

Comment: jQuery's [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (and the related [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)) use [`.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), [`.fail()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/), [`.always()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/), and [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to deal with the request results. Since it's asynchronous but doesn't expose the promise, you won't be able to treat the results synchronously.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. You are not going to catch an error outside of the event listener.

Comment: So I can catch even the errors inside and outside the `addEventListener` with one `try catch`